# How does this regex work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
"Rubymonk Is Pretty Brilliant".match(/ ./, 9)
```

How is the answer "P" calculated from this regex?

- use the `match` method on the string
- passes two arguments, a regular expression and the position in the string to begin the search.
- returns the character 'P'

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question or an answer? Because it looks like you've already answered your own question.

Comment: Question is about WHY.

Comment: yes why the answer is 'P'

Answer (score 5):

The criteria you posted from the Rubymonk grader answer this succinctly:

> passes two arguments, a regular expression and the position in the
>   string to begin the search

But let's examine that in more detail. `match` is being passed two arguments:

- `/ ./`, a regular expression
- `9`, the starting position in the string

The regular expression tells us that we're looking for a space () followed by any character (`.`).

The starting position tells us to start at position 9 (I). So instead of applying that regex against "Rubymonk Is Pretty Brilliant", we're applying it against "Is Pretty Brilliant".

In the string "Is Pretty Brilliant", where is the first place we encounter a space followed by another character? "Is[ P]retty Brilliant", right? Thus `match` finds a result of `P` (that's space-P, matching the regex, not just P.)

To see this more clearly and to experiment further with regexes, you can try it in an irb session or in your browser using [Rubular](http://rubular.com).

Comment: Good answer. Consider using the shorthand for it like this: "Rubymonk Is Pretty Brilliant"[/ ./,9]

Comment: I didn't know one could do that in ruby (`"Rubymonk Is Pretty Brilliant"[/ ./,9]`) - nice one.  In my (oldish - 1.9.3) version of ruby, making the second argument anything other than 0 always causes the result to be nil however.  My docs say "If a numeric parameter follows the regular expression, that component of the MatchData is returned instead".  What does (eg) `1` mean, in the context of "that component of the matchdata"?

Comment: Great answer, really well explained thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Just google for RegEx + ruby, You will find explanation of regex syntax)

/ANYTHING-HERE/

Will look for ANYTHING-HERE in the text.

In Your example its (/ ./,9):

/SPACE DOT/

So it will look for space followed by single character (Dot -> single character).

9 will be "I" from the string. And that is not space, so it will go on 2 characters right. Will find space, and then will find single character "P".

That is the result.